# iPhone in-app screen saver

Tags: iphone, screensaver

How can I create an iPhone in-app screen-saver?

E.g:
After 30 seconds the app hasn't been used a "screen-saver" starts. Where screen saver is a movie, a photo slideshow etc.

Comment: That is a strange thing to do

Comment: if a user isnt touching/using the device for 30 seconds, he is probably not looking at it!

Comment: not that strange ...
This is not the usual app store app scenario:
Imagine the iPad is in a store and everyone can play with it. After 30 seconds the last user touched something, it starts the screen-saver (with some ads/video/etc).

When I'll finish the project I'll write a post about it and it will be clearer :)

Comment: Makes a little more sense with that explanation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to count 30 seconds from any user interaction in this case, so I would suggest having a global `NSTimer` created in you app delegate that creates and makes prominent your screen saver view if it reaches 30 seconds.

Monitor for touch events and view rotations - if these happen, invalidate your timer and create a new one.

If you don't like the 'create/destroy' aspect of this, you could log a 'last input time' from any touch/rotate event and your timer can compare this to the current time each tick.

Comment: I think I'll go with the last input time ... sounds a lot better than create/destroy ...